# Non-class type error in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, non-type

I need some help with a C++ program I'm working on.

I'm taking a class on operating systems so our first few weeks have been a crash course in C programming, but now we are supposed to upgrade our C program to C++. My professor showed us a few pieces of example code and showed a few tutorials to us, but they've only gotten me so far.

We are using a header file, a .cpp file to implement the functions, and a test file (which is where my errors are coming from.

```
//dll.h

#ifndef _DLL_H
#define _DLL_H
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class dll{
public:
typedef struct _Node
{

    struct _Node *pNode;
    struct _Node *nNode;
    int nodeValue;

}sNode;

typedef struct
{

    sNode first; 

}DLList;

dll();
~dll();
void init(DLList *DLL,int d);
void sort(DLList *DLL);
void print(DLList *DLL);

};

#endif
```

The main .cpp file:

```
//dll.cpp

using namespace std; 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "dll.h"

dll::dll(){

    cout<<"Constructor called"<<endl;

}

dll::~dll(){

    cout<<"Destructor called"<<endl;

}

void dll::init(DLList *DLL, int d)
{

    sNode *node;    
    sNode *pNode;
    pNode = &(DLL-> first);
    pNode->pNode = NULL;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<d; i++)
    {

            node = (sNode*) malloc(sizeof(node));
            node-> nodeValue = rand();
            node-> pNode = pNode;
            node-> nNode = NULL;
            pNode-> nNode = node;
            pNode = node;

    }

}

void dll::print(DLList *DLL)
{

    int i= 1;
    sNode *nNode = DLL-> first.nNode;   
    while(nNode != NULL)

    {

            cout<<("%d.  %d\n",i,nNode-> nodeValue);
            cout<<("");
            nNode = nNode-> nNode;
            i++;

    }

}

void dll::sort(DLList *DLL)
{

    int change = 1;
    while(change== 1)

    {

            change = 0;     
            sNode *current = DLL-> first.nNode;
            while(current-> nNode != NULL)

            {

                    if(current-> nodeValue > current-> nNode-> nodeValue)
                    {

                            int temp = current-> nodeValue;
                            current-> nodeValue = current-> nNode-> nodeValue;
                            current-> nNode-> nodeValue = temp;
                            change = 1;

                    }

                    current = current-> nNode;
            }

    }

    }
```

Now the test file, which is where my error keeps popping up:

```
//testDLL.cpp


using namespace std; 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "dll.h"

int main()
{

    cout<<("Doubly Linked List before sorting: \n");    
    dll::DLList DLL;
    dll *test =  new dll();
    test.dll::init(&DLL,5);
    test.dll::print(&DLL);
    test.dll::sort(&DLL);
    cout<<("\nDoubly Linked List after sorting: \n");
    test.dll::print(&DLL);
    return 0;
}
```

As the program is written now, I keep running into this every time I try to compile (using g++ on the linux command line):

```
testDLL.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
testDLL.cpp:17:7: error: request for member ‘init’ in ‘test’, which is of non-class type ‘dll*’
testDLL.cpp:19:12: error: request for member ‘dll:: print’ in ‘test’, which is of non-class type ‘dll*’
testDLL.cpp:21:12: error: request for member ‘dll:: sort’ in ‘test’, which is of non-class type ‘dll*’
testDLL.cpp:25:12: error: request for member ‘dll:: print’ in ‘test’, which is of non-class type ‘dll*’
```

I'm totally stumped by this, so any help you guys can give me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `test.dll::init` should be `test->init()`.

Comment: Oh ***please*** get rid of all those empty lines in your code, they are horrible for readability.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - Sorry about that, that's how the grader prefers it. I'll edit it now

Comment: @Code-Guru - When I tried that I get `testDLL.cpp:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `dll::init(dll::DLList*, int)` for each of the method calls. Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you compiling your code?

Comment: @Code-Guru - `g++ testDLL.cpp`

Comment: @Jonathan You need to include *all* source files in the command line args.

Comment: On a object-oriented note, things are a bit awry: Your only 'class' (`dll`) has no member variables, but all its methods take a pointer to a `DLList` struct as a parameter. Maybe that belongs in the object? Also, in C++ you wouldn't write `typedef struct{..} foo`.

Comment: @Code-Guru - Holy crap I 'm an idiot. That worked. Thanks a ton man, you have just saved my grade

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `dll` as a pointer the declaration is correct.

```
dll* test = new dll();
```

If you are using `dll` as an object the declaration should be:

```
dll test;
```

This will cause the constructor and destructor to invoke automatically.

If you are using `dll` as a pointer the call to `init` should be (you don't have to check for NULL, but it will help prevent your program from crashing):

```
if (dll != NULL) {
    dll->init(&DLL, 5);
}
```

If you are using `dll` as an object the call to `init` should be:

```
 dll.init(&DLL, 5);
```